# algorithm for binning of 3D coordinates (in R or any other language)

Tags: r, algorithm, 3d, coordinates, binning

I am trying to bin 3D coordinates.

I have coordinates of a molecule moving through a protein, from over 800 simulations... What I want is to bin these data to get means, variances and how many points I have in a bin.

I imagine it like this:
the space containing my 3D coordinates is split up into smaller 3D cubes (3D bins) defined by breaks().

What I need is all my x,y,z coordinates in these smaller 3D bins to calculate the mean and variance of these data.

Does this make sense?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My input looks like this:

```
x<-c(1.1,1.2,4.3)
y<-c(3.4,5,2,3.2)
z<-c(10.1,10.3,12)
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
```

and the output should be organised by bins with dat having additional info on which bin the coordinates belong to:

```
x y y bin_x bin_y bin_z
```

Comment: could you show an expected output ?I'm unsure to get the logic behind your code actually

Comment: [edit] your question to complete it, comments are not intended for this.

Comment: Correcting myself, if it's a cube which each side divided in 10 parts, BINs should be a list of 1000 entries. I still don't get your code logic against your description btw.

Comment: your are rigth...  because I only have 3 coordinates in this example set. (so 10x10x10 entries in BINs)

Comment: My code logic is most likely VERY flawed. Not a programmer at all, am a biochemist who likes computers ;)

Comment: I might be completely off, but would creating a crouping variable using `paste` solve your problem? If your intention is to group your data by small cube and do calculations on the subsets, it might work?

Comment: Heroka, can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: It will be to long for a comment, so I will attempt an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. I might be completely wrong here, but your question is hard to answer without some expected output. I went on your intention of calculating mean and variance for each small cube, so created a grouping variable.

```
#generate some data with some more points and a vale

set.seed(32587)

n=500
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(n,min=0,max=10),
                  y=runif(n,min=0,max=10),
                  z=runif(n,min=0,max=10))


#create bins (using 'cut', no need to do this manually or in a loop)
#I have removed the labels, so each bin is just a number.

#breaks have been changed to allow for actual binning 

breaks<-seq(0,10,1)

dat$bin_x <- cut(dat$x, breaks=breaks, labels=F)
dat$bin_y <- cut(dat$y, breaks=breaks, labels=F)
dat$bin_z <- cut(dat$z, breaks=breaks, labels=F)

#create grouping variable with some string formatting for readability
dat$bin_all <- with(dat, sprintf("%02d.%02d.%02d",bin_x,bin_y,bin_z))

head(dat)


library(data.table)

m_dat <- melt(setDT(dat),measure.vars=c("x","y","z"))


res <- m_dat[,.(mean_value=mean(value),variance_value=var(value),
                n_value=.N),by=list(bin_all,variable)]
res
```

Comment: Dear Heroka, thanks. I do not need to aggregate the "value" variable, but I want to calculate means and variance of the coordinates in each small cube. How do I do that elegantly (without for loops)? I need to test it with my complete dataset too, might take a while...

Comment: So to be clear: you have a more continuous coordinate variable than you indicated with the integers, and you want mean and variance of the coordinates in each cube?

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you. I've changed the data-generating mechanism and number, to populate the bins more.

Comment: Heroka, it works! :D thanks a lot. I am very happy right now.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a new question in the future, please put some consideration into the form your input and expected output takes :).

Answer (score 1):

```
#Matrix of bins
 mat <- cbind(rep(1:10, each = 100), rep(rep(1:10, each = 10), 10), rep(1:10, 100))
Data Frame of coordinates
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,3), y = c(2,6), z = c(8,10))
```

Outputs the row of mat which match the 3 values of the row of df1

```
apply(apply(df1, 1, function(x) 
apply(mat,1, function(y) 
sum(x[1] == y[1], x[2] == y[2], x[3] == y[3])) ), 2, 
function(z) which(z ==3))
```